# MySQL query to show records with current date on top and others as per descending order

Tags: php, mysql, date, sql-order-by

I am using the following query in my database,

```
SELECT b.sales_id,b.category_id,b.sale_starts,b.sale_ends 
FROM tbl_sales b WHERE b.active=1 
UNION
SELECT b.sales_id,b.category_id,b.sale_starts,b.sale_ends 
FROM tbl_sales b INNER JOIN tb_category c ON  b.category_id=c.cat_id 
WHERE c.cat_keyword LIKE 'a' ORDER BY sale_ends  DESC
```

and getting the result as follows,

```
sales_id  | category_id         |sale_starts | sale_ends 
----------|---------------------|------------|--------------
 1        |   10                | 2012-03-31 | 2012-04-30     
 2        |   11                | 2012-03-22 | 2012-04-27
 3        |   25                | 2012-03-31 | 2012-04-25
 4        |   12                | 2012-04-05 | 2012-04-11
```

Now i need to get the result as follows, ie the row which has `today's date/current date as`sale_ends must be shown in the top of the order (assuming today's date/current date is `2012-04-11`), like shown below-

```
sales_id      | category_id         |sale_starts | sale_ends 
    ----------|---------------------|------------|--------------
     4        |   12                | 2012-04-05 | 2012-04-11 (today's date)
     1        |   10                | 2012-03-31 | 2012-04-30     
     2        |   11                | 2012-03-22 | 2012-04-27
     3        |   25                | 2012-03-31 | 2012-04-25
```

Need help in this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this ORDER BY clause with condition -

```
ORDER BY IF(sale_ends = DATE(NOW()), 0, 1), sale_ends DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the whole thing in another SELECT and use ORDER BY

```
SELECT * FROM (     
     SELECT b.sales_id,b.category_id,b.sale_starts,b.sale_ends 
     FROM tbl_sales b WHERE b.active=1 
     UNION
     SELECT b.sales_id,b.category_id,b.sale_starts,b.sale_ends 
     FROM tbl_sales b INNER JOIN tb_category c ON  b.category_id=c.cat_id 
     WHERE c.cat_keyword LIKE 'a' ORDER BY sale_ends  DESC
) AS all_sales
ORDER BY (sale_ends=CURDATE()) DESC, sale_ends DESC
```